# How to get year in format YY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
select Year(Creation_Date) 
from Asset_Creation 
where Creation_Date = @Creation_Date
```

I am executing this query where I am getting year as `2013` when supplied today's date. I want the query to return only 13 of 2013. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(Creation_Date), 2) YY 
  FROM Asset_Creation 
 WHERE ...
```

Sample output:

```
| YY |
------
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 13 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfa46/1)** demo

Answer (score 9):

For SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT FORMAT(@Creation_Date, 'yy')
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're storing up a year 2100 problem by only using two digits, then I assume you only need code that works between 2000 and 2099. In which case, just subtract 2000:

```
select Year(Creation_Date) - 2000
from Asset_Creation 
where Creation_Date = @Creation_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTRING(Year(Creation_Date), 2, 2)
from Asset_Creation 
where Creation_Date = @Creation_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

How about;

```
SUBSTRING(YEAR(Creation_Date), 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very helpful function here

call it like this

```
SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), ‘MM/DD/YY’)
```

function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnFormatDate (@Datetime DATETIME, @FormatMask VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(32)
    SET @StringDate = @FormatMask
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘YYYY’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘YYYY’,
                         DATENAME(YY, @Datetime))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘YY’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘YY’,
                         RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @Datetime),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘Month’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘Month’,
                         DATENAME(MM, @Datetime))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘MON’,@StringDate COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)>0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘MON’,
                         LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime)),3))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘Mon’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘Mon’,
                                     LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime),3))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘MM’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘MM’,
                  RIGHT(’0′+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘M’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘M’,
                         CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘DD’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘DD’,
                         RIGHT(’0′+DATENAME(DD, @Datetime),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘D’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘D’,
                                     DATENAME(DD, @Datetime))   
RETURN @StringDate
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in SQLServer you can use the format argument of the Convert function set to 1  The syntax will be Convert(varchar(10), @YourDate, 1)